# How to map drive as system account via batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to map a network drive as a the local system account on a server, I can achieve this fine by running psexec -I -s cmd.exe then the net use command

My issue is the drive disconnects on reboot, even with persistent set to /p:yes

I’ve been trying to create a batch file that will run at startup that will run cmd via psexec, and then execute the net use command.

I can get to this point where cmd runs but I can’t get the next part of the command for net use to appear in the new cmd window.

Has anyone got any ideas/a better way of doing this altogether?

As a side note, the network share requires separate credentials to connect to it so it has to be mapped in such a way that credentials can be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the file as a .cmd file type and placing it in the shell:startup folder? It will run automatically every time you log in to the pc.